# How can I implement scoped foreach in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, scope

I get data from an excel spreadsheet, loop over it, save it to an array. Then, I loop over that data twice.

I do:

```
foreach($someData as $key => $value) {

}
```

and I will need to foreach that same array again. Is there any way I can make it so i can use $key => $value again without causing any problems?

Comment: Why don't you loop once ?

Comment: When you say "loop over the data twice", is the first loop completing before you start the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you only need one loop, but to answer your question, you can just do this:

```
foreach($someData as $key => $value) {
    #do stuff here
}

foreach($someData as $key => $value) {
    #do more stuff here
}
```

`$key` and `$value` will get overwritten during each iteration of each loop, so there's no danger here.

Your question is a little unclear, though—if you have a `foreach` inside of another `foreach` and want to use the same set of variable names for each loop's keys and values, use a function. That's the only way to create a new local scope in PHP:

```
function nested_loop($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        #do more stuff here
    }
}

foreach($someData as $key => $value) {    #same names, different variables
    #do stuff here

    nested_loop($value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought they got overwritten, but I didn't know that it was harmless.

Comment: well, it's harmless when used correctly, but there's always the potential that you, the programmer, will get confused about what a particular variable contains and make a mistake (happens to me more than i'd like). so it's probably a good idea *not* to use the same names for both sets of variables ... typically something like `$key1` and `$key2` is a better idea. when it makes sense, i like to prevent myself from making mistakes in the first place.